# from ps4 import BeautifulSoup doens't work.. not capital letters, not file name bs4.py, uninstalled and installed multiple times

Tags: python, linux, beautifulsoup

The code is just

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

print(BeautifulSoup.__file__)
```

and the error shows

```
  File "/path/to/wtfisgoingon.py", line 1, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ImportError: cannot import name 'BeautifulSoup' from 'bs4' (unknown location)
```

Downloaded BeautifulSoup4 on Linux Ubuntu 20.04 using:

`sudo pip3 install bs4` and `sudo pip3 install beautifulsoup4`, and `sudo pip3 list` will see bs4 and beautifulsoup downloaded (version 0.0.1 and 4.11.1 respectively).

Checked everywhere and most people import it with "beautifulsoup" or "Beautifulsoup4" but I think my import is in correct format. Or people name the file bs4.py or some name included in the module or something so it won't work, however my file name is something impossible to be seen in the module.

Please help! Thank you.

Comment: It can find the `bs4` module, so that's at least a start.  Let's see what's in it.  Show us the output of this code: `print(dir(bs4))`

Comment: it shows: `['__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']`

Comment: Hmm.  Try `print(bs4.__file__)`

Comment: `['__bool__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__']`

Comment: That's the output of `bs4.__file__`?  really?

Comment: my bad that's the output of dir(bs4.__file__), the output of bs4.__file__is `None`

Comment: How about `bs4.__path__`?

Comment: `_NamespacePath(['/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/bs4'])`

Comment: Well, that looks right.  I'm not sure why that error is happening.

Comment: Show us the output of these commands:  `ls /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/bs4` and `grep BeautifulSoup /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/bs4/*`

Answer (score 0):

You should only need to import beautifulsoup4. I find it useful to use a venv or virtualenv, and once you are in the virtual environment all you need to import is `python3 -m pip install {package}`. You can create a virtual environment using `python3 -m venv {venv name}`, and activate using `cd {venv name}` and then `source bin/activate` (this is for mac, pretty sure it works on other os) https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html this might help

Answer (score 0):

you need create venv

python -m venv myvenv

then use venv pip3 install bs4

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Comment: Hey Apple, pip3 install bs4 only tells me that the requirements already satisfied for bs4, beautifulsoup4 and soupsieve, and the error still shows, thanks.